# Nested Horizontal CSS Menus

Tags: css, html

I'm having a hard time with nested horizontal hovers. I either can't get the nested submenu hidden or I can't get it to show on hover. I've added the following to get the first sub menu hidden:

```
enter code here
.menu-holder ul li ul li ul li{
    display:none;
 }
```

and the following to try and get it to display:

```
enter code here
 .menu-holder > ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul{
  display: inline;
  }
```

While the hiding is working the displaying is not. I'm not sure that this is how I should initially hide the submenu anyway.

One thing I haven't addressed yet is to get the menus to fill the screen to the left before they fill to the right.

```css
 .wrapper {
     width:500px;
     height:500px;
  color:black;
 }
 .menu-holder ul {
     margin: 2px 0 0px 25px;
     padding: 0;
     list-style-type: none;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li {
     position: relative;
     float: left;
     padding: 0px 10px 0 10px;
     margin: 0px 0px 100px 0px;
     border-left: 1px dotted white;
 }
    
 .menu-holder ul li:hover{
     background-color: green;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li:hover ul {
     display: block;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul:hover {
     display: block;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li.current-menu-item
{
 background:#999
}
 .menu-holder ul li ul li ul li{
    display:none;
 }
 .menu-holder > ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul{
     display: inline;
 }

 .menu-holder ul li a {
     font-family: arial, sans-serif;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: bold;
     display: block;
  color:black;
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
     border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul {
     float: none;
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 42px;
     left: 0px;
     margin: -1px 0 0px 10px;
     padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
     white-space: nowrap;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul li {
     position: static;
     float: none;
     display: inline;
     padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
     margin: 0px 0px 0px -10px;
     background-color: #025179;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul li a {
     display: inline;
     margin: 0 0px 0 0px;
     padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
     font-weight: normal;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0;
     border-radius: 0;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul li:first-of-type {
     -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
     border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul li:last-of-type {
     -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
     border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li:first-of-type {
     border-left: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="menu-holder">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a id="close0" href="#" onclick="showiframe(this.id); return false;">
          Follow This</a>

        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a id="about" href="" onclick="showiframe(this.id); return false;">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>Item1</li>
          <li>Item2</li>
          <li>Follow This
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href="#">Item1</a>
              </li>
              <li>Item2</li>
              <li>Item3</li>
              <li>follow This
                <ul class="submenu">
                  <li><a href="#">Item1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>Item2</li>
                  <li>Item3</li>
                  <li>Item4</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">menu item 3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">menu item 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- menu-holder end -->
</div>
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this is the effect you are looking for.

```css
 .wrapper {
     width:500px;
     height:500px;
  color:black;
 }
 .menu-holder ul {
     margin: 2px 0 0px 25px;
     padding: 0;
     list-style-type: none;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li {
     position: relative;
     float: left;
     padding: 0px 10px 0 10px;
     margin: 0px 0px 100px 0px;
     border-left: 1px dotted white;
 }
    
 .menu-holder ul li:hover{
     background-color: green;
 }

 .menu-holder ul li:hover > ul {
     display: block;
 }
  .menu-holder ul li.current-menu-item
{
 background:#999
}

 .menu-holder ul li a {
     font-family: arial, sans-serif;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: bold;
     display: block;
  color:black;
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
     border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul {
     float: none;
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 100%;
     left: 0px;
     margin: -1px 0 0px 10px;
     padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
     white-space: nowrap;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul li {
     position: static;
     float: none;
     display: inline;
     padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
     margin: 0px 0px 0px -10px;
     background-color: #025179;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul li a {
     display: inline;
     margin: 0 0px 0 0px;
     padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
     font-weight: normal;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0;
     border-radius: 0;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul li:first-of-type {
     -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
     border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul li:last-of-type {
     -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
     border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li:first-of-type {
     border-left: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="menu-holder">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a id="close0" href="#" onclick="showiframe(this.id); return false;">
          Follow This</a>

        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a id="about" href="" onclick="showiframe(this.id); return false;">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>Item1</li>
          <li>Item2</li>
          <li>Follow This
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href="#">Item1</a>
              </li>
              <li>Item2</li>
              <li>Item3</li>
              <li>follow This
                <ul class="submenu">
                  <li><a href="#">Item1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>Item2</li>
                  <li>Item3</li>
                  <li>Item4</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">menu item 3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">menu item 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- menu-holder end -->
</div>
​
```

Comment: that is close, but let's say in the second sub menu you remove  <li>Item1</li>
          <li>Item2</li>
Then the menu is too far over to get to. What I was hoping to do was keep the postioning but extend the width of that item to reach the hover.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a semantically correct implementation of what you are looking for:

### HTML

```
    <nav>
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="primary">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="#">Item</a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="#">Item</a>
            <div class="secondary-nav-container">
              <ul class="secondary">
                <li class=""><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class=""><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

### CSS

```
    nav .primary-navigation {
      float: right;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    nav .primary-navigation li {
      float: left;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    nav .primary-navigation li:last-child {
      margin-right: 10px;
    }

    nav .primary-navigation a {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0px 10px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      line-height: 2.2em;
    }

    nav.mobile .secondary-navigation a {
      font-size: 1em;
      line-height: 2.3em;
    }

    nav .secondary-nav-container {
      position: absolute;
      top: 36px;
      left: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 36px;
      display: none;
    }

    nav .primary-navigation > li.active .secondary-nav-container,
    nav .primary-navigation > li:hover .secondary-nav-container {
      display: block;
      z-index: 4;
    }

    nav .primary-navigation > li:hover .secondary-nav-container,
    nav.mobile .primary-navigation > li:hover .secondary-nav-container{
      z-index: 5;
    }

    nav .secondary-navigation, nav.mobile .secondary-navigation {
      float: right;
    }
```

Context:
I devised this HTML/CSS only solution for a CMS I developed a few years ago.

Show/Hide effects:
These can be done using css transitions or using javascript.

Comment: Please explain how this applies. Being a novice at some of this, I don't see anything but a vertical list when I put it in jfiddle.