# CSS for direction of list elements in nested Drop-Down Menu?

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to change the code to handle arbitrary nested items? I have no clue how to this to apply for multiple levels. The following works just for 2 levels. But if i add a 3. level it fails. I think this can be done cleverly without writing manually each level?

I want that it can be adjusted to arbitrary many childs and it should be work with hover and clicks.

Thank you very much.

```css
 .nav ul {
          list-style: none;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
        }

        .nav ul li {
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            border-bottom: none;
            height: 86px;
            line-height: 86px;
            font-size: 14px;
            display: inline-block;
            float:left;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .nav ul li a {
          text-decoration: none;
          color:#000000;
          display: block;
          transition: .3s background-color;
          padding:0 24px;
        }

        .nav ul li a:hover {
          background-color: #5c89c7;
          color:#FFFFFF;
        }

        .nav a {
            border-bottom:none;
        }

        .nav li ul {
            position:absolute;
            display:none;
            width:inherit;
         text-align:left;
        }

        .nav li:hover ul {
            display:block;
        }

        .nav ul li ul li {
          display: block;
          float:left; /* newly added */
          height:auto; /* newly added */
          line-height:34px; /* newly added */
        }
```

```html
<div class="nav"> <!-- Start of Nav Bar -->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT&nbsp;US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">PROGRAMS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">RESOURCES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">GET&nbsp;INVOLVED</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT&nbsp;US</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">AAAA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BBB</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CCCC</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">OOOO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">BBBB</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: (Adding any more levels to what you already have in the snippet, would be first and foremost a UX fail, IMHO. These types of menu a tricky enough to use for people with any kind of motoric  / sensory impairments with one or two levels already.)

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you wanted? I just added a `>` in `.nav li:hover ul`.

See comments in code below. ZZZZ, XXXX, and YYYY are added by me.

```css
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav ul li {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 86px;
    line-height: 86px;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

.nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#000000;
  display: block;
  transition: .3s background-color;
  padding:0 24px;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #5c89c7;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}

.nav a {
    border-bottom:none;
}

.nav li ul {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    width:inherit;
    text-align:left;
}

/*.nav li:hover ul { OLD CODE
    display:block;
}*/

.nav li:hover > ul { /* ADDED the charcter '>'  */
    display:block;
}


.nav ul li ul li {
  display: block;
  float:left;
  height:auto;
  line-height:34px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT&nbsp;US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">PROGRAMS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">RESOURCES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">GET&nbsp;INVOLVED</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT&nbsp;US</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">AAAA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BBB</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CCCC</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">OOOO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ZZZZ</a>
                          <ul> <!-- ADDED -->
                            <li><a href="#">XXXX</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">YYYY</a></li>
                          </ul>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but the last elements shoudl also "open up" horizonatlly, like the parents. Now they are list below each other

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex-inline and > for this approach of making menus.

```css
.nav ul {
          list-style: none;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
        }

        .nav ul li {
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            border-bottom: none;
            height: 86px;
            line-height: 86px;
            font-size: 14px;
            display: inline-block;
            float:left;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .nav ul li a {
          text-decoration: none;
          color:#000000;
          display: block;
          transition: .3s background-color;
          padding:0 24px;
        }

        .nav ul li a:hover {
          background-color: #5c89c7;
          color:#FFFFFF;
        }

        .nav a {
            border-bottom:none;
        }

        .nav li ul {
            position:absolute;
            display:none;
            width:inherit;
         text-align:left;
        }

        .nav li:hover > ul {
            display: inline-flex !important;
        }

        .nav ul li ul li {
          /*display: block;*/
          float:left;
          height:auto;
          line-height:34px; 
        }
```

```html
<div class="nav"> <!-- Start of Nav Bar -->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT&nbsp;US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">PROGRAMS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">RESOURCES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">GET&nbsp;INVOLVED</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT&nbsp;US</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">AAAA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BBB</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CCCC</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">OOOO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">BBBB</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Thnak you! This looks almost I want. But If you add new levels you see that you get more and more to the right. This looks not great and is not I like. Because I need to have the child lists open up maybe from whole left (of the page) or just under the main parent: So all child levels under "Contact us" should appear starting direct under the position of "Contact us" or from the whole left page.

Comment: Is this possible to do in an easy way?

Comment: Your welcome my friend, not in an easy way but you can change every class with display flex and then fix the overlapping issues. If I found a time to do that, I will share the way you want it. Good Luck. You can also look at this documentation maybe it would help you : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: That would be amazing if you can do! :-) Also the only thing I found which comes close as the shifts are not too much, is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29684847/nested-horizontal-css-menus

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a multi-level dropdown. This is easier to do with separate classes rather than all one class (`nav`). I rewrote it for the sake of organization, but the design tweaks are really up to you! When running this snippet, make sure to use full screen because StackOverflow's snippet will distort the display a little bit.

```css
.menu1 li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: white;
}

.menu1 li:hover {
  background-color: #5c89c7;
}

.menu1 li:hover>ul {
  display: inline;
}

.menu1 a {
  border-bottom: none;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.menu1 a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.menu2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}

.menu2>li {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  background: #999999;
}

.menu2>li:hover {
  background: #CCCCCC;
}

.menu3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -150px;
  width: 150px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}

.menu3>li {
  height: 30px;
  background: #999999;
}

.menu3>li:hover {
  background: #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu1">
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">SERVICES</a>
    <ul class="menu2">
      <li><a href="#">PROGRAMS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">RESOURCES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">GET INVOLVED</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
    <ul class="menu2">
      <li><a href="#">AAAA</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">BBB</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CCCC</a>
        <ul class="menu3">
          <li><a href="#">OOOO</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">BBBB</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need it the list open up fom top to down and like before. 

But this is something I look for somehwere else. There I want to have the main topics be vertical and the rest opens horizonatlly. So like you posted but the other way around (now the maain topics are horizontally.)